# cant get drag and drop to use localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I need help trying to get the drag and drop clone to use the stored version of the textarea.

i.e. A user can currently drag and drop the textarea into the field on the right hand side. However, each textarea on the left also allows users to edit the text for the next time they open the page.

Both of the above work.

However, I cannot get the drag and drop utility to take into account the edited version of the textarea. i.e. if a user changes the text in 'option 1' to 'hello' and comes back later, the textarea will now contain 'hello' because of local storage, but when they drag and drop this textarea into the field on the right, the original 'option 1' text is copied instead of the stored 'hello' value

Here is the link to my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hemang2/QkRpp/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after fixed your all bug,

Here is the link to fiddle (updated) : http://jsfiddle.net/E8RHE/

check it out.

Comment: thanks! that actually adds a nice bit of functionality! but it still doesn't drop the edited value from the textarea. any thoughts?

Comment: if  user change text option1 to 'hello' and then drop on right hand side.. then right hand side text changed to hello. right?

Comment: that's exactly what I want, but it still says the original option1 value "Option 1..." instead of the changed value